# c# replacing integer

Tags: c#

I have 50 buttons in my project as all are linked, when pressed, to a method. And now, when a button has been pressed I want it to go invisible. Since I don't want my code to contain 50 IF statements to check which
button that has been pressed:

```
If(sender == Button1)
{     
    Button1.visible = false;
}
```

This code gets very long if I ill have almost the same block of code when only the button name changes 50 times.
Is there anyway to this in another way to get a shorter code?

Maybe: If a String variable contains the name of the button?

```
string buttoncheck = Button1;
```

And then in the upper code insert buttoncheck instead of Button1 since buttoncheck contains the value/name of Button1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Button button = (Button) sender;
button.Visible = false;
```

Comment: +1 Assuming nothing but a button is hooked to the method, this is the simple and straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like

```
var x = sender as Button;
if(x != null){
    x.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By casting it to a Button, you can just use the reference provided by `sender` to set the visibility of the button that fired the event.

```
if(sender is Button)
{
  ((Button)sender).Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: No need for `as` if you've already checked with `is`, just cast it and avoid the redundant check.

Answer (score 2):

```
((Button)sender).Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your event, you have a sender.

You can cast your sender to you Button object type.

```
var button = sender as Button;

if(button != null)
    button.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

If 50 buttons share same functionality, subscribe their Click event to the same event handler, and do this:

```
Button button = sender as Button;    
if (button != null)
   button.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Button button = sender as Button;
button.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the sender.

```
var button = (Button) sender;
button.Visible = false;
```